# How can we use an iPhone camera as a webcam on Windows?

Tags: unity, ios, video

I am developing a game on **Windows** and I want to use my **iPhone 11p** as a **webcam** (for video streaming).

I saw some tutorial videos on YouTube, yet they only work for development on iOS platform in Unity.

So how can we use an iPhone camera as a webcam in an app on the Windows platform?